# Which package do I have to use to print capdot (⩀) symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols, mathematics

I would like to use the capdot (⩀) symbol but unfortunately it seems impossibile to use it so that I thought to put a question where I ask clarification about: I point out the symbol is present into the [TheComprehensiveLATEXSymbolList](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathit/symbols-letter.pdf). To follow the code I am trying to use.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}

\setcounter{equation}{-1}

\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}

\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont

\end{document}
```

Comment: why `\usepackage{newtxtext}` to use a times roman clone then `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont` to use latin modern?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Honestly I did not remember when I add it and for why: the document I am writing now consists of 70 pages.

Comment: The symbol is in [MnSymbol](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) so you have to load that package

Comment: @DG' Thanks: the package Mnsymbol works perfectly: obviously if you will write an answer I will accept it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of "teaching a person to fish":

When using the Comprehensive Symbols List, the tables tell you which packages you need to load to use them. `\capdot` shows up in Table 50, which describes the binary operators in the MnSymbol package.

[image]

One way to find out how to load these symbols is to search CTAN for "MnSymbol", which will helpfully give you [this result](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol?lang=en); the documentation there tells you that you should `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`. Importantly, though, the documentation also tells you that

> The MnSymbol package is incompatible with the
> amssymb and amsfonts packages. It automatically loads the amsmath and textcomp packages. If you want to pass options to these packages you can either put the corresponding
> \usepackage command before the \usepackage{MnSymbol} or you can include the options in the \documentclass command.

Seeing that you are loading both `amssymb` and `amsfonts` in your document, you may wish to pay attention to this.

Comment: The table caption gives the package name for `\usepackage`; but I still suggest reading the documentation as there are incompatibilities between various symbol packages and the documentation is one place where it will be listed.